# How to cross reference a main dataframe with a reference dataframe to compare values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Scenario:
I have 2 Dataframes, one is a datatable of data taken from an application. The other is a spreadsheet containing 'Threshold Data'.

I need to go through the main dataframe and find 'Name A' within the reference document and then look at the Thresholds for that Name and see if the value within the main dataframe is within or exceeds these thresholds.

Once that is complete I need to report on each one which falls outside of its threshold and build up a new datatable.

I am reasonable new to Python so at the moment I have just built the 2 dataframes within my code ready to be cross referenced.

This is what I have so far with a merge function:

```
def shareclass_1(writer):
    print("Running Shareclass 1 Check")
    ref_shareclass = pd.read_excel(config.mapping_doc_path, sheet_name='Shareclasses')
    print(ref_shareclass)
    filename = import_input_file()
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='EOD UK Share Class FX')
    shareclass_merge = df.merge(ref_shareclass, on='Portfolio')
```

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZIB4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Like jezrael said, example data is totally necessary in this example

Comment: I hope my updated post is a bit easier to undertstand now!